# SQL Server 2008 R2 - Islands and Gaps

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, gaps-and-islands

I have a simple 2 column table. PctGain contains weekly percentage stock market gains. WSeqkey contains a contiguous integer value that increments each new week. There are approximately 3300 rows in the above table. Here is a sample.

```
PctGain WSeqKey
0.12%   4407
0.31%   4406
0.68%   4405
1.14%   4404
0.95%   4403
0.38%   4402
4.57%   4401
-1.94%  4400
1.17%   4399
-0.32%  4398
```

What would like help solving, and learning how to do along the way is...write/run a query that will tell me when the positive and negative sequences begin and end. Something like

```
Negative Beg 4398
Negative End 4398
Positive Beg 4399
Positive End 4399
Negative Beg 4400
Negative End 4400
Positive Beg 4401
Positive End 4407
```

Thank you in advance for solving this and helping me learn along the way.

Frank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should do the job [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/64876/3)

It finds islands of sequential data with the same value for `SIGN` and alllocates them the same grouping value using Itzik Ben Gan's row number technique then groups them and aggregates them. The `CROSS APPLY ... VALUES` unpivots the `MIN` and `MAX`

```
;WITH T1
     AS (SELECT *,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SIGN(PctGain) 
                                       ORDER BY WSeqKey) - WSeqKey AS Grp
         FROM   YourTable),
     T2
     AS (SELECT MIN(WSeqKey)  AS BeginSeq,
                MAX(WSeqKey)  AS EndSeq,
                SIGN(PctGain) AS Sign
         FROM   T1
         GROUP  BY Grp,
                   SIGN(PctGain))
SELECT CASE Sign
         WHEN -1 THEN 'Negative'
         WHEN 0 THEN 'Equal'
         WHEN 1 THEN 'Positive'
       END AS [Sign],
       Descriptor,
       SeqKey
FROM   T2
       CROSS APPLY (VALUES('Begin', BeginSeq),
                          ('End',   EndSeq)) V(Descriptor, SeqKey)
ORDER  BY SeqKey
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone I looked at the gaps/islands URL on MSDN and figured it out.

I dumped just the WSEQKEYs into a temp table (#gaps) while filtering on pctgain > 0 and then used the following sql:

```
SELECT t1.gapID as startOfGroup, MIN(t2.gapID) 
as endOfGroup FROM (SELECT gapID FROM #gaps tbl1 
  WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM #gaps tbl2 
    WHERE tbl1.gapID - tbl2.gapID = 1)) t1
  INNER JOIN (SELECT gapID FROM #gaps tbl1 
  WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM #gaps tbl2 
    WHERE tbl2.gapID - tbl1.gapID = 1)) t2
  ON t1.gapID <= t2.gapID   GROUP BY t1.gapID
  order by t1.gapID desc
```